# Placing limit on API calls based on DOM insertion promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to limit the number of API calls I am making if I already have enough elements on the DOM.

But it seems in between the promises and the actual insertion, my check isn't being triggered in time.

JS:

```
$scope.fireAPICalls = function() {
  if($scope.wikiArticles.length < 3) {
    $scope.wikiAPI.getRandomArticle().success(function(data) {
      angular.forEach(data.query.pages, function(page, key) {
        $scope.wikiArticles.push(page);
      });
    });
    $timeout($scope.fireAPICalls, 0);
  }
}

$scope.wikiAPI = (function(){
  return {
    getRandomArticle : function() {
      return $http.jsonp("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts|categories&explaintext&exintro=&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK", function (data) {});
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="article-listing" ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="article in wikiArticles"><span>{{article.title}}</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="category in article.categories">{{category.title}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br>{{article.extract}}
</div>
```

How do I ensure that I always have a maximum of 3 elements in the `wikiArticles` array?

Comment: Why the duplicate question??

Comment: @Stewie I made some changes from jQuery AJAX to using Angular's $http service and tried updating the post but it kept showing blank page. So I tried deleting and re-making the question but I guess it never got deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `fireAPICalls` again only when you got response on 1st call.

Change `fireAPICalls` to:

```
$scope.fireAPICalls = function() {
  if($scope.wikiArticles.length < 3) {
    $scope.wikiAPI.getRandomArticle().success(function(data) {
      angular.forEach(data.query.pages, function(page, key) {
        $scope.wikiArticles.push(page);
      });
      $timeout($scope.fireAPICalls, 0);
    });// end success    
  }// end if
}
```

The `$timeout($scope.fireAPICalls, 0);` should be into `success`

From your code we call `fireAPICalls` without waiting for any response (since `wikiAPI` is async)

Comment: I see it now, thanks! (: Guess it's time for me to take a break, my brain clearly isn't functional anymore.

Comment: Maybe write comments like `// end success  ` and `// end if`. Suppose you confused with braces :)